# Overheating Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, overheating

Does replacing Ubuntu OS with a Windows OS ( probably Windows 7 ) gets rid of overheating problem in Ubuntu ?

I have tried all the following options:

- Tried all the three options in the 'Additional Drivers' options in 'Softwares & Updates'
- Installed bumblebee, nvidia, nvidia-prime
- Thermalpad,TLP.

After 5 minutes of laptop usage, the core temperatures goes very high.I can't even place it in my lap.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. What version Ubuntu? What computer? Do you know how hot it gets? Do you already have another OS that you can boot? Does the overheating occur if you just boot the Ubuntu Live DVD? Cheers, Al

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. Laptop -> Hp Envy TS 15-J109TX 4th GenQuad Core i7-4700MQ 2GB NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M. Ubuntu is the only operating system in my laptop. Previously heating starts whenever I run the emulator in android studio, but for the past one week it gets heated even after 2 minutes of normal usage. After starting the laptop, even when the laptop is doing nothing, it gets heated automatically.

Comment: You didn't say if the overheating occurs when just booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD. Also, is the laptop very dusty, or been exposed to a dusty environment? Sometimes laptops can accumulate a lot of dust in the fans, and it requires cleaning. Sometimes the thermal paste on the CPU requires reapplication. Please answer the first 2 questions. Cheers, Al

Comment: I don't know why you are asking about a Ubuntu Live DVD twice. I neither didnt mention anything about a live ubuntu nor a Live Ubuntu DVD in either the question description or the comment. Answer to your reply--> I am not running any live versions. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: I'm asking about the Ubuntu Live DVD because I wanted to eliminate some other software issue with your installed Ubuntu. I can't make recommendations on how you might fix your problem, unless I know if the problem is hardware or software. You also didn't answer my dust question. Also, please check your tone. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

Try to purge bumblebeed and then follow the steps I descrive above.

Re Install bublebeed:

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic

Restart, go to System Configuration->Sotware Updates-> Aditonal Controls

Aditonal Controls

and select the NVIDIA driver(these controllers are privative) you can try all of them to see wich one is the best so you can have the amazing 55°C temperature I have.

You can find the oficial documentation [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the open source driver for the nvidia GPU , and reinstall bumblebbe (as Cam T says). Try to install cpufrequitl 
`$ sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils` . 
I had an overheating issue only with the Ubuntu OS and doing this solved the problem.